# Webpage monitoring script is returning false positives

Tags: bash, if-statement, html, cron, monitor

I am trying to automate a process which previously was consuming a full-time job: monitoring a series of websites for new posts. This seemed like a relatively simple scripting problem, so I tackled it, wrote a bash script, and set it to run every minute in the crontab. It works great, but after the page changes, it keeps returning false positives for an hour or so, and I can't for the life of me figure out why. It resolves itself after a while, but I don't want to deploy the script until I understand what's happening. Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

SITENAME=example

wget http://web.site.url/apache/folder/$(date +%Y)/$(date +%m)-$(date +%B) -O $SITENAME.backend.new --no-cache 
touch $SITENAME.backend.old
diff $SITENAME.backend.new $SITENAME.backend.old > $SITENAME.backend.diff

if [ -s $SITENAME.backend.diff ]
then  sendemail -xu myaddress@mydomain.com -xp password -f myaddress@mydomain.com -t myaddress@mydomain.com -s smtpout.secureserver.net -u $SITENAME -m backend \
&& cp $SITENAME.backend.new $SITENAME.backend.old \
&& echo true

fi
```

Comment: Can you show what `$SITENAME.backend.diff` contains ?

Comment: A few lines of HTML, which are largely identical, except for some timestamps, which are off by several hours. Hmmm... do you think they're load-balancing between multiple servers? I'll do some testing.

Comment: Yes, it looks like they have multiple servers that run similar, but slightly different pages. Their links on one server are relative, while on another, they're absolute. It looks like my connection switches between these about every five minutes. Does anyone have any ideas as to a possible way to make it work, despite minor changes in the page?

Answer (score 0):

If the only difference between diffs are *absolute* or not *absolute* links, consider using the `--convert-links` switch for `wget`, like the man said :

> ```
>   -k
>   --convert-links
> ```
>
> After the download is complete, convert the links in the document to make them suitable for local viewing.  This affects not only the visible hyperlinks, but any part of the document that links to external content, such as embedded images, links to style sheets, hyperlinks to non-HTML content, etc.

This will convert links to *absolute* links.